# factory is unable to convey data to another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am building a spa with angular and slim framework. As per the bellow mentioned code, what i am trying to do is, login page controller will pass data to landing page controller upon successful submission of user/psw. When i place the factory outside the http call/ log in function it gets the data but on the landing page factory does not deliver the data. And when i place it inside it stops to work. Please help me....

**this factory is for sharing data across controllers**

```
appDls.factory('sharedFactory', function () {
    var dataTobeShared = {};
    var interface = {};
    interface.add = function (d) {
        dataTobeShared = d;
    }
    interface.put = function () {
        return dataTobeShared;
    }
    return interface;
});
```

**this controller is for the main portal user redirection and portal rendering**

```
appDls.controller('DlsappController', ['$scope', '$state', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory', '$window', function ($scope, $state, multipartForm, sharedFactory, $window) {
    $scope.Userdata = [];
    $scope.login = function () {
        var url = "../scripts/routes.php/authen";
        multipartForm.post(url, $scope.login).then(function (d) {
            $scope.Userdata.push(d.data[0]);
            sharedFactory.add($scope.Userdata);
            $window.location.href = '../portal/landing.php';
        });
    }
}]);
```

**this controller is for landing page routing**

```
appDls.controller('landingController', ['$scope', '$state', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory', function ($scope, $state, multipartForm, sharedFactory) {
    $scope.UserInfo = sharedFactory.put();
    $scope.$watch('UserInfo', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        /*here we can use the user data from login page*/
        if (newValue.length == 1) {
            alert(newValue[0].fullname);
            $state.go(newValue[0].proftype);
        } else {
            alert("user not logged in successfully!");
            $state.go('default');
        }

    }, true);

}]);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to stop shouting - using ALL CAPS LIKE THIS is rude pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...I have edited question....

Answer (score 0):

When you do `sharedFactory.add($scope.Userdata);` your `$scope.Userdata` is another object, which is not watched by `landingController`. By reassigning `dataToBeShared` in `sharedFactory.add` function, you lose the reference to original object, so it is not reachable anymore from code.

To make `landingController` see the changes you need either to reimplement `sharedFactory.add` function to push values in `sharedFactory.dataTobeShared` **array** or use some event-based notification, not $watch.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6vfwq3y/1/) to illustrate my words.

Answer (score 0):

```
appDls.factory('sharedFactory', function () {
    var dataTobeShared = {};
return 
  {
    add: function (d) {
        dataTobeShared = d;
    }
    put: function () {
        return dataTobeShared;
    }
  }

});


appDls.controller('DlsappController', ['$scope', '$state', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory', '$window', function ($scope, $state, multipartForm, sharedFactory, $window) {
    $scope.Userdata = [];
    $scope.$watch('login',function () {
        var url = "../scripts/routes.php/authen";
        multipartForm.post(url, $scope.login).then(function (d) {
            $scope.Userdata.push(d.data[0]);
            sharedFactory.add($scope.Userdata);
            $window.location.href = '../portal/landing.php';
        });
    }
}]);


appDls.controller('landingController', ['$scope', '$state', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory', function ($scope, $state, multipartForm, sharedFactory) {
    $scope.UserInfo = sharedFactory.put();
    $scope.$watch('UserInfo', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        /*here we can use the user data from login page*/
        if (newValue.length == 1) {
            alert(newValue[0].fullname);
            $state.go(newValue[0].proftype);
        } else {
            alert("user not logged in successfully!");
            $state.go('default');
        }

    }, true);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The watcher needs to fetch the value from the factory on each digest cycle, and update the $scope variable.

```
appDls.controller('landingController', ['$scope', '$state', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory', function ($scope, $state, multipartForm, sharedFactory) {
    //$scope.UserInfo = sharedFactory.put();
    //$scope.$watch('UserInfo', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.$watch(sharedFactory.put, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        //UPDATE scope variable
        $scope.UserInfo = newValue;
           /*here we can use the user data from login page*/
        if (newValue.length == 1) {
            alert(newValue[0].fullname);
            $state.go(newValue[0].proftype);
        } else {
            alert("user not logged in successfully!");
            $state.go('default');
        }

    }, true);

}]);
```

The original code only set the scope variable once upon initialization of the controller. It needs to fetch the value from the factory on each digest cycle.